# Отправка GET POST запроса android

Tags: java, android

Нужна помощь. Не могу за коннектится сервером.

Такой мой код:

```
String url = "https://myserver/api/?name=randomname";
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
    try {
        postparams.put("login", "login");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        postparams.put("password", "pasword");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, postparams, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                Log.i("debugResult", response.toString());
                JSONArray jsonObject = response.getJSONArray("status");
                String status = jsonObject.toString();

                ClientnData clientnData = new ClientnData();

                clientnData.setStatus(status);
                clientnDataArrayList.add(clientnData);

                clientDataAdapter = new ClientDataAdapter(ClientDataActivity.this, clientnDataArrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(clientDataAdapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
});

    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Сервер принимает параметры запроса через метод GET, а аутентификацию через  POST
и так при каждом запросе. Но в моем случае сервер возвращает  {"error":"Не указан логин или пароль"}, Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что вы хотите сделать? Отправить get запрос или post ?

Comment: Отправить post запрос. параметры запроса сервер принимать через Url но авторизацию проверяет через post т.е. в теле post отправляется логин пароль, при каждом запросе.